# Skip address output when using GNU nm utility

Tags: linker, nm

Is there any ideas how to skip address output while outputting via nm?

Here is an excerpt from nm output:

```
0040cb94 T _fwrite
0040c8e0 t _get_ptr_from_atom
00410948 t _get_ptr_from_atom
00412fac T _GetAtomNameA@12
00412ffc T _GetCurrentProcess@0
00413004 T _GetCurrentThread@0
00412fec T _GetCurrentThreadId@0
0041305c T _GetHandleInformation@8
0040134f T _main
```

I want to get this output:

```
T _fwrite
t _get_ptr_from_atom
t _get_ptr_from_atom
T _GetAtomNameA@12
T _GetCurrentProcess@0
T _GetCurrentThread@0
T _GetCurrentThreadId@0
T _GetHandleInformation@8
T _main
```

How to accomplish this task using git-bash command line?
I have looked for corresponding option in nm utility but seems to me there is not such option.

Comment: better awk '{ print $2 " " $3}'  Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe it through `awk`:

```
nm ... | awk '{ print $2 " " $3 }'
```

or perhaps a regex if there are other lines of output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

```
nm ARGS | cut -c10-
```

This will display characters 10 and onwards of each line.